# Compile a class into a different folder

Tags: java, javac

I have this structure of folders that contains Computer.java class

> MY_JAVA_PACKAGES/com/matteo/hardware/Computer.java

And another directory outside called MY_JAVA_SOURCES where I want to insert the compiled class

My Java book is telling me to use this in command line inside MY_JAVA_SOURCES folder

```
javac -d $HOME/MY_JAVA_PACKAGES Computer.java
```

But I got an error because the compiler cannot find the file Computer.java, so I started to think that the error could be caused by the directory name, so I used the `pwd` command outside every directory to know what is my base directory and I got "/home/matteo" as a result and I tried with this inside the MY_JAVA_SOURCES to see what happen

```
javac -d $home/matteo/MY_JAVA_PACKAGES Computer.java
```

But I still got the same error.

Comment: If you are in `MY_JAVA_SOURCES`, then `javac` doesn't find `Computer.java`, because that file is in `MY_JAVA_PACKAGES/com/matteo/hardware/`. You need to specify the full path to the file (or the path relative to your current directory). BTW: it is pretty weird to use something with **sources** in the name as the location to put compiled files. I would guess you're `Computer.java` file should be in `MY_JAVA_SOURCES/com/matteo/hardware/` instead.

Comment: this is the translation from my book after compiling the Computer.java in MY_JAVA_SOURCES -> "In this way we create in directory MY_JAVA_PACKAGES the structure com/matteo/hardware where will be placed the file Computer.class"

Comment: You're right, my .java is in MY_JAVA_SOURCES and with the shell command "javac -d $HOME/MY_JAVA_PACKAGES Computer.java" I create the new structure in dir MY_JAVA_PACKAGES

Comment: If your sources are in `MY_JAVA_SOURCES`, and you're compiling from the directory `MY_JAVA_SOURCES`, then you should use `javac com/matteo/hardware/Computer.java to compile the file.

Comment: This work, it create the file .class in com/matteo/hardware but I want the structure com/matteo/hardware/Computer.class inside the MY_JAVA_PACKAGES directory using the -d flag.  The Shell that the book use is `[thp@localhost MY_JAVA_SOURCES]$ javac -d $HOME/MY_JAVA_PACKAGES Computer.java`

Comment: I left out the `-d ...` option for brevity. You need to use `javac -d path/to/MY_JAVA_PACKAGES com/matteo/hardware/Computer.java` (where `path/to` needs to be replaced with the absolute or relative path to MY_JAVA_PACKAGES (eg `../MY_JAVA_PACKAGES` if it is in the same parent directory as `MY_JAVA_SOURCES`).

Comment: Ok the book got me headaches because the file Computer.java included `package com.matteo.hardware;` without effectively create the structure so I tried to remove the structure and just left the file Computer.java inside the MY_JAVA_SOURCES then the Shell `javac -d /home/matteo/MY_JAVA_PACKAGES/Computer.java` automatically has generated the structure. . anyway, thank you for help and time :)

Comment: The `package com.matteo.hardware` is correct for files in a directory `com/matteo/hardware` and you should have left it in.

Comment: Ok I solved with (inside MY_JAVA_SOURCES/com/matteo/hardware, without being inside that I couldn't find the Computer.java) `javac -d home/matteo/MY_JAVA_PACKAGES Computer.java` I had forgotten the space after the directory structure that's why I got **error : no source files**. .